# Perform load test in bot framework

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I am developing a bot using. Net bot framework and using direct line channel.

What is the step step guideline for load testing a bot?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do so is to create a mock channel (or message sink). Please see the following blog for steps on the approach:

https://blog.botframework.com/2017/06/19/Load-Testing-A-Bot/

Comment: It is mentioned in the article to not use direct line. So what should be my approach?
Should I use direct line?
Is using mock channel a good way to ensure load testing is done properly for your bot?

Comment: Using a mock channel allows you to remove the channel from the testing scenario. This allows you to focus on the performance of your bot itself, without affecting the channel connectors (directline, Microsoft Teams, etc). You should not concern yourself with testing with these connectors as they are handled outside of your control and are monitored for performance/load. By confirming that your bot code itself can handle the load you expect or wish to prepare for, that allows you to be in the best position to ensure excellent performance when implemented with the correct channels/connectors.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Azure web Performance Test but It's will depreciated soon in 2020.